# Get formatted HTML from CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in my web app, and I'm at a loss as to how to get the contents of the editor with HTML formatting.

```
var objEditor = CKEDITOR.instances["sectionTextArea"];
var q = objEditor.getData();
```

This will get me the text entered in CKEditor, without any markup.

However,

```
var q = objEditor.getHTML();
```

will return a null value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

getHTML isn't a method of a CKEditor object, so instead of null you should have a javascript error.

The method defined by the api is [getData()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData) if that doesn't work then you have some other problem in your code, try to use an alert to verify the contents at that moment.

Comment: If you mean that they should have used some console.log, you should have realized that the user was trying to use a non-existing method, so if he had looked at the console he would have seen the error. Instead of explaining him all the details about how to debug javascript (and the possible need to install some extra add-on or switch browser, remember that he asked this four years ago), the bullet-proof method is to use an alert that provides the info and there's no need to explain it further.

Comment: IMHO, using alert for debugging purposes is very bad practice and should not be adviced to anyone recklessly. (Since SO is a well known resource especially for beginners)

Comment: So it would have been better for you if I wrote: "or learn how to debug javascript with a proper browser" ? That's not helpful. The alert always works in every browser without any requirement. I would love to see you debug a web page in mobile four years ago without an alert.

Comment: @Wolle using `alert()` instead of `console.log()` is good for beginner because you can pause execution when using `alert()`, If it was console.log() thew would have to use debugger keyword to pause execution. Both console.log() and alert() has its own advantages. I know most beginners use alert() instead of console.log(), but that doesn't make one or other a bad practice, Just don't use it in production, If it was bad, the browsers would have removed it.

Answer (score 17):

just to know that the right method for this is `getData()` didn't help me. I did not know how to use it on the CKEditor object. and `CKEDITOR.getData()` doesn't work.

this is how `getData()` is used on the CKEDITOR object:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.my_editor.getData()
```

...where `my_editor` is the id of your textarea used for CKEditor.

The opposite of it is `setData()`:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.my_editor.setData("<p>My Text</p>");
```

Answer (score 10):

To get htmlData from editor you should use the code snippet bellow:

```
var htmldata = CKEDITOR.instances.Editor.document.getBody().getHtml();
```

If this solution won't work, check if you have `BBCode` plugins uninstalled.

Comment: exception document is undefinded

Comment: Keep in mind that you should replace `Editor` by your instance name, for example, in my case it was: `CKEDITOR.instances.sfw_fc_fccd_e2_dui27_fcUse_fccd_e16_dui27_fcUse_fccd_e2_dui31_tbTextGeneratorUse.getData()` since I was using it in ASP.Net and the instace name was `sfw_fc_fccd_e2_dui27_fcUse_fccd_e16_dui27_fcUse_fccd_e2_dui31_tbTextGeneratorUse`.

Answer (score 7):

Please update ckeditor config.js with the following line

```
config.fullPage = true;
```

This will return the full html when you request getData();

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
CKEDITOR.instances["id"].getData()
```

Answer (score 2):

in **ckeditor 5**, you can get the html data with `editor.getData()`

here is an example:

```sh
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log(editor.getData());
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the preview plugin to get the full HTML content, hope it helps.

```js
CKEDITOR.getFullHTMLContent = function(editor){
 var cnt = "";
 editor.once('contentPreview', function(e){
  cnt = e.data.dataValue;
  return false;
 });
 editor.execCommand('preview');
 
 return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java Users...

After pressing the submit button, the request goes by HTTP Post method. This Post request also contains the formatted html in the parameter named using the name attribute of the textarea.

So, if your textarea is something like...

`<form method="post" action="createPDF.do">    <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1"/>

    <input type="submit"/>    </form>`

Then, after pressing the submit button, you can get the formatted html in your servlet/controller by :

```
String htmlContent = request.getParameter("editor1");
```

You can also pass this variable containing the formatted html ('htmlContent') to ITEXT (or some other pdf converters) to create the pdf...

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I had trouble finding an answer that made sense and returned the actual HTML, including images. If your ckeditor instance is attached to a textarea, you can simple get the value of the textarea to get the HTML.

For instance, if you're using jQuery:

```
$('#my_editor').val()
```

No need to go digging through the API.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. without modifications there seems to be no data in the textarea, all the data is inside the iFrame.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. I have this working in production. Maybe you need to use the jquery command to create it as well? `$j('#element').ckeditor();`

Answer (score 0):

If you have two **CKEditor**, you can use code bellow:

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
<textarea name="editor2"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2' );

var objEditor1 = CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"];
alert(objEditor1.getData()); // get html data

var objEditor2 = CKEDITOR.instances["editor2"];
alert(objEditor2.getData()); // get html data
```

[**Online Demo (jsfiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/wxazxpjj/)

Answer (score 0):

I used the insert media feature in editor and .getData() did not return the required HTML to show the video thumbnail icon. The following worked for me to get the final HTML:

```js
$(".ck-content").html()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.YOUREDITOR.element.getHtml();
```

with CKEDITOR.instances.YOUREDITOR.element you select a DOM element and if you use 
CKEDITOR.instances.YOUREDITOR.element.getHtml();
you can get all html from editor element.

Comment: Please don't add just one line. Explain your answer.

Comment: sorry ,  when select a editor, you can select a element DOM

Comment: with 
elemtDom = CKEDITOR.instances.YOUREDITOR.element;
and get HTML from that element with getHtml();
so you can use ** CKEDITOR.instances.YOUREDITOR.element.getHtml(); **