# Get particular content from ckeditor

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor and bellow is my textarea for ckeditor and it's content and how can i get content only inside the `<p id="footer"></p>` using jquery

```
<textarea id="cheditor_text" name="cheditor_text" rows="10">
<p> welcome to our company </p>
<p id="footer">
Copy right @ exak=mple.com
</p>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this link , 
it is helpful .

Try using [getData();](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData)

[Useful Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440680/get-formatted-html-from-ckeditor?rq=1)

Comment: What you've proposed is a hard path that would require regex to extract #footer contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/WU2PX/)**

```
txt = $('#cheditor_text').text();
html = $('<div>').append(txt).find('#footer').prev()[0].outerHTML;
```

Without using outHTML

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/WU2PX/2/)**

```
txt = $('#cheditor_text').text();
pTag = $('<div>').append(txt).find('#footer').prev();
alert($('<div>').append(pTag).html())​
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['cheditor_text'].getData();
$(value).find('#footer').html();
```

or

```
$('#cheditor_text').ckeditor(function( textarea ){
$($(textarea).val()).find('#footer').html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even retrieve contents of this element directly from editor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.your_editor_instance.document.getById( 'footer' ).getHtml();
```

However I think that there's something wrong with the logic of what you want to do. Retrieving contents this way can be dangerous if users omit `id` attribute or use it twice. This is something you cannot rely on.

You should better create two editors, one with the content and the second for `#footer`. Another possibility is the [inline editing feature](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline) introduced in CKEditor 4 that allows editing web pages as they are. In my opinion you should really rethink your idea to make it stable and reliable.