# CKEditor get data in html format

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor

I am trying to get data entered by the user in the textarea. 
I have tried  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData(), 
 CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.document.getBody.getHtml()
both of them return the html in string format. 
I want to display the data in html format.

Is there any API that can give me the data in html?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get formatted HTML from CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440680/get-formatted-html-from-ckeditor)

Comment: I looked at the solutions but none of them seemed to have worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can get the body element of the editors iFrame via `CKEditor.instances.<instance-name>.document.$.body`.

This will get you the actual HTML element, which you can use however you like.

Comment: does the <instance-name> refer to the name of the CKEditor?